# How can I run Java on my browsers?

Tags: java, google-chrome, firefox, applet

I have installed Java 8 (SDK) but when this is installed also is installed the JRE too. I want to execute an applet into chrome or firefox browser, but always when I executed appears a message that I need to install the plugin to execute this.

Is there a way to specify to the browser, where was installed my jdk or jre and execute this?

Comment: `appears a message that I need to install the plugin to execute this.`. Install the java plugin for browser. This might not be in ur jdk/jre.

Comment: I installed many times. When I installed, I restart my browser and always when I test if works appears the message again, that I need to install the plugin. Also, the plugin that recommend is Java 7, Is there a way to download the plugin with Java 8 for browsers?

Comment: What operating System do you use?

Answer (score 0):

From Firefox, go to plugins, and make sure it doesn't say "never activate" next to the plugin in question. 
I do not have chrome on this computer, but I would imagine it is a similar procedure.

Comment: I checked on the plugins in firefox, but doesn't appear on the list, and I have installed many times.